# How to install crosswalk lite plugin using cordova cli

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, crosswalk

I would like to know how to use "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" but instead install the lite version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [**Ionic Framework**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/overview/) it becomes very easy.
So, using Ionic you could choose among all available browser listed by the Ionic CLI command `ionic browser list`.
Output example:

```
Android - Browsers Listing:

Available - Crosswalk - ionic browser add crosswalk
         Version 8.37.189.14 Published
         Version 9.38.208.10 Published
         Version 10.39.235.15 Published
         Version 11.40.277.7 Published
         Version 12.41.296.5 Published
(beta)   Version 13.42.319.6 Published
(canary) Version 14.42.334.0 Published

Available - Crosswalk-lite - ionic browser add crosswalk-lite
(canary) Version 10.39.234.1 Published
(canary) Version 10.39.236.1 Published
```

Then, for example, install an [alternate browser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html) with the command:

```
ionic browser add crosswalk-lite@10.39.236.1
```