# Crosswalk-lite with cordova

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk

I am spending days trying to make my app embedded with crosswalk-lite instead the normal crosswalk. Can anyone that have done it explain the method?

Comment: Please post the code you currently have so that others can help you troubleshoot it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It's not about code, it's about the fact that crosswalk-lite documentation is not enought clear, it just says to do the same steps of crosswalk but if i follow them then i get the normal binaries....

Comment: Maybe my suggestion in this answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003505/how-to-install-crosswalk-lite-plugin-using-cordova-cli/33165700#33165700

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42314666/3966458

Answer (score 6):

FINALLY I MADE IT !!

First of all the reason why it always goes to download the normal binaries is that the crosswalk-lite is not in official release, but i had no problems with my app so here we go:
Go to your project folder than edit this file:

platforms/android/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/*yourapp*-xwalk.gradle

replace

`repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
  }
}`

to be

`repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}`

then add near the line 71 after cdvPluginPostBuildExtras.add({:

`def liteSpec = "org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:1.0.0.1"`

and edit the dependecies rule to be

`dependencies {
        compile liteSpec
    }`

remember that 1.0.0.1 is our self created version

Now download [from the crosswalk-lite repository](https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk-lite/android/canary/) the version you want to embed, i have tested with the version 17.46.451.1 , download just the .aar file.
This version has both x86 and armv7 reources so you have to unzip the .aar (is actually a zip file ) and then delete the file

res/raw/libxwalkcore.so.x86   [ if you want to make apk for armv7 devices ]

res/raw/libxwalkcore.so.armeabi_v7a [ if you want to make apk for x86 devices ]

this is because it will trigger the error duplicate resources, as i noticed.

Now zip again the folder without the resource and rename it to .aar

And finally the magic touch, (if you haven't installed maven do apt-get install maven2)

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=*YOURFILE*.aar -DgroupId=org.xwalk -DartifactId=xwalk_core_library -Dversion=1.0.0.1 -Dpackaging=aar`

Now you can build your app with the crosswalk-lite embbeded,
it may seems difficult but it's not , and it worth every mb saved to the apk

Comment: Great work. It's really sad that Ionic team did not do this upgrade to the cli, even after a lot of complains everywhere

Comment: A heads up, the later versions of the crosswalk-lite does not have the libraries in `res/raw` , also ran into an issue with building it, there's something else that is missing from what was mentioned in your post.

Comment: Did you noticed that now you can download aar files with already separated binaries? and what issue did you get? please be more detailed

Comment: Are you using a platform like Meteor?  I'm afraid of spoil off my meteor project installing a package with maven without using meteor procedure

Answer (score 0):

1) Crosswalk-lite just added maven server in https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk-lite/android/maven2/. so you don't need to configure your local maven anymore.

2) In the latest version, there is no more res/raw. Now embedding Lite has no different with embedding crosswalk normal build.